# My Choropleth Map gets stuck loading and never finishes?

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

Relatively new here and new to Python in general, but trying to work with Plotly Express to create myself a Choropleth map that allows me to color-code custom data on countries. However, I'm having trouble actually loading the map up. I've been able to load the native Choropleth map with none of my data, but when I link my own geojson data set to the function it gets stuck loading on line 30. I haven't quite been able to figure out why, since it just gets stuck and gives me nothing else to troubleshoot with.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import random
from token_file import token
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import json


with open('documents/countries.geojson') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

countries = {}

for features in data["features"]:
    if features["properties"]["ISO_A3"] != "-99":
        name = features["properties"]["ADMIN"]
        iso = features["properties"]["ISO_A3"]
        geo = features["geometry"]
        val = random.randint(0, 100)
        values = pd.Series([name, iso, val], index=["Name", "ISO", "Val"])
        countries[name] = values
    else:
        continue

countries = pd.DataFrame(countries)
countries = countries.transpose()

print(countries)

px.set_mapbox_access_token(token)
map = px.choropleth_mapbox(countries, locations="ISO", zoom=1, hover_name="Name", hover_data=["ISO"],
                           color="Val", color_continuous_scale="Viridis", mapbox_style="carto-positron")
map.update_layout(margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0})
map.show()
```